# biblatex cite page translation

Tags: biblatex, babel, apacite

I want to display the spanish form of a parencite, with `\parencite[see][page 80]{he_optimal_2018}` command.

I'm using `biblatex` and `babel`, I've no problem in other translations as in `\printbibliography`, but I can't figure out this command isn't working, biblatex documentation says:

> The package is completely localised and can interface with the babel and polyglossia
> packages.

The spanish form looks like this:

> (véase He & Wang, 2018, página 80)

Instead, it outputs:

> (see He & Wang, 2018, page 80)

This is the latex document I have:

**References.bib**

```latex
@article{he_optimal_2018,
    title = {Optimal selection of air expansion machine in Compressed Air Energy Storage: A review},
    volume = {87},
    issn = {1364-0321},
    url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1364032118300170},
    doi = {10.1016/j.rser.2018.01.013},
    shorttitle = {Optimal selection of air expansion machine in Compressed Air Energy Storage},
    pages = {77--95},
    journaltitle = {Renewable and Sustainable Energy Reviews},
    shortjournal = {Renewable and Sustainable Energy Reviews},
    author = {He, Wei and Wang, Jihong},
    urldate = {2021-05-30},
    date = {2018-05-01},
    langid = {english},
    keywords = {Compressed Air Energy Storage, Expander Classification, Expander Modelling, Optimal Expander Selection},
}
```

**CAES.tex**

```latex
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}

%%%%%%%   Document configuration   %%%%%%%
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%  Other  %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%% Bibliography %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa, sorting=ynt, citestyle=apa,hyperref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%    Title    %%%%%%%%%%%
\title{title}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage

    A lot of text
    \begin{displayquote}
        Kim and Favrat presented energy and exergy analysis of different types of micro I-CAES and A-CAES systems. It indicated that quasi-isothermal compression and expansion processes are more preferable than adiabatic compression and expansion, especially for applications with high pressure ratios \parencite[see][page 80]{he_optimal_2018}
    \end{displayquote}

    \clearpage
    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: you are disabling the localization by printing "page" explicitly. Use simply [80] as page number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex` translates the string that it typesets on its own. It does not translate arbitrary user input. The pre- and post-note in citations can in principle be arbitrary text, so that is not translated.

There is, however, one important exception. `biblatex` can localise the "page"/"pages" prefix. But in order for that to work you should not write `page` or `pages` into the postnote yourself, you should just give the number and let `biblatex` figure out the rest.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  Lorem \autocite[véase][380]{sigfridsson}
  ipsum \autocite[véase][380-382]{sigfridsson}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (véase Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998, p. 380) ipsum (véase Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998, pp. 380-382)]

For the simple case of `see`->*véase* we could actually set up a rudimentary translation system. But again, this would not be able to translate arbitrary text, but only predefined strings (of which `see` is one).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{prenote}{%
  \ifbibstring{#1}
    {\bibstring{#1}}
    {#1}%
}

\begin{document}
  Lorem \autocite[see][380]{sigfridsson}
  ipsum \autocite[see][380-382]{sigfridsson}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```